# Por que o valor em bytes é exibido como 4?

Tags: c, ponteiro, sizeof

Eu estou usando uma matriz 2x2 com um simples ponteiro e quero exibir os valores do mesmo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct matriz mat;

struct matriz {

    int lin;
    int col;
    int *arr;
};

mat* cria(int lin, int col) {

    mat *m = malloc(sizeof(mat));
    m->lin = lin;
    m->col = col;
    m->arr = malloc(lin * col * sizeof(int));
    return m;
}

void exibe(mat *m) {

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(m->arr); i++) {
        printf("%3d", m->arr[i]);
    }
}
int main() {

    mat *m;
    m = cria(2, 2);
    m->arr[0] = 24;
    m->arr[1] = 16;
    m->arr[2] = 13;
    m->arr[3] = 56;

    exibe(m);

    return 0;
}
```

Assim `sizeof(m->arr)` exibe 4. Ele não deveria exibir 16 bytes (4 x 4)?

Comment: Vou comentar aqui porque acho que não tenho autoridade para responder, mas acredito que o compilador retornará o tamanho do tipo no qual é definido o ponteiro e não o tamanho para onde o mesmo aponta. Isto é, como ele é definido como `int` e na sua arquitetura esse tipo consome 4 bytes de memória, então o `sizeof` do mesmo será 4. Tem uma [discussão](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeof-a-pointer-pointing-to-an-array) sobre isso no SOen.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Não. O que está guardado em `m->arr`? O retorno de [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), que é um ponteiro. Em arquitetura 32 bits um ponteiro tem 4 bytes, se deseja o tamanho da sequência, tem que passar como argumento para a função. Mas tenho a impressão que nem é o caso, o que deseja é a quantidade de elementos, que também deveria passar. Como a estrutura tem essa informação, nem precisa passar nada, pode só usar `lin * col`.

Na verdade este código parece ter outros problemas, mas não investiguei a fundo. E o código não está criando matriz alguma, só uma sequência simples.

Comment: thmm concordo que não é uma matriz, já que o acesso e feito por um único índice.

Answer (score 1):

O programa que você quer deveria ser assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct matriz mat;

struct matriz {
    int lin;
    int col;
    int *arr;
};

mat* cria(int lin, int col) {
    mat *m = malloc(sizeof(mat));
    m->lin = lin;
    m->col = col;
    m->arr = malloc(lin * col * sizeof(int));
    return m;
}

void destroi(mat *m) {
    if (m == NULL) return;
    free(m->arr);
    free(m);
}

int ler_elemento(mat *m, int i, int j) {
    return m[i * m->col + j];
}

int definir_elemento(mat *m, int i, int j, int valor) {
    m[i * m->col + j] = valor;
}

void exibe(mat *m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m->lin; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->col; j++) {
            printf("%3d ", ler_elemento(m, i, j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    mat *m;
    m = cria(2, 2);
    definir_elemento(m, 0, 0, 24);
    definir_elemento(m, 0, 1, 16);
    definir_elemento(m, 1, 0, 13);
    definir_elemento(m, 1, 1, 56);

    exibe(m);
    destroi(m);

    return 0;
}
```

Observe que criei as funções `ler_elemento` e `definir_elemento` para centralizar, abstrair e encapsular a lógica de acessar-se os elementos nas posições corretas. Desta forma, as demais partes do código não precisam se preocupar com os detalhes mais complicados de como fazer para achar a posição correta no array de elementos da matriz e nem mesmo vão precisar se preocupar em saber que a estrutura `mat` tem um array lá dentro. Com isso, se mais tarde você quiser alterar a forma como a estrutura `mat` organiza os seus dados, apenas as funções `ler_elemento`, `definir_elemento` e `cria` precisarão ser alteradas, o que evita mudanças em cascata, onde a alteração de um pequeno detalhe forçaria a necessidade de promover-se grandes mudanças no código todo.

Também acrescentei uma função para desalocar o `mat`. É uma boa prática sempre desalocar aquilo que você aloca, e portanto, sempre que você tiver uma função que cria alguma coisa por meio de alocação dinâmica de memória, você já deve imediatamente ter a mão a função que desaloca essa mesma coisa.

Quanto ao `sizeof(m->arr)`, isso daí vai te dar o tamanho do ponteiro `m->arr` ao invés do tamanho da matriz. Observe que `arr` é do tipo `int *`, e portanto `sizeof(m->arr)` é o mesmo que `sizeof(int *)`. O resultado é 4 porque um ponteiro para inteiro ocupa 4 bytes no seu computador, não importando para onde esse ponteiro aponta ou mesmo se ele aponta ou não para um endereço de memória válido.

A finalidade do `sizeof` é medir quanta memória **estática** uma determinada estrutura ocupa, e ele é determinado em tempo de compilação, e não de execução. Para alocação dinâmica de memória, o tamanho dos dados alocados depende de informações que só estão disponíveis em tempo de execução, e portanto não há como o compilador saber qual ele seria. A solução é você calcular o tamanho você mesmo se precisar, e no fim das contas, você não precisa disso para apenas exibir a matriz na tela.